# Manipulate table and query in presto

Tags: sql, presto, trino

Hi I want to do SQL Presto query for the data table (say **user_data**) looks like

```
user | target | item | score |  type | other cols
------------------------------------------------
 A   |    D   |   7  | 0.1   | T     | other vals
 A   |    D   |   7  | 0.11  | T     | other vals
 A   |    D   |   4  | 0.2   | F     | other vals
 B   |    D   |   3  | 0.4   | F     | other vals
 A   |    H   |   4  | 0.3   | F     | other vals
 B   |    G   |   4  | 0.1   | T     | other vals
 A   |    E   |   2  | 0.2   | T     | other vals
```

Here, the all column values are not necessarily unique for each user-target-item set. For example, for user A and target D and item 7, the score can be 0.1 or 0.11 depending on the rest of other columns. So I want to keep the **maximum score for each user-target-item set** in the output table.

With this data table, I would like to generate the following output.

**Output 1: For each "user" and "type", create arrays [target, item, maximum score, other vals] for each user-target-item set.**

```
user |            type T         |       type F     
----------------------------------------------------------
 A   | [D, 7, 0.11, other vals], | [D, 4, 0.2,  other vals]
       [E, 2, 0.2,  other vals]  |
 B   | [G, 4, 0.1,  other vals], | [D, 3, 0.4,  other vals]
```

Or if you have any other better way to get array of columns for each unique user-target-item set, please let me know as well.

A huge thank you in advance!

Comment: It is not very clear what is the goal here. The desired output does not match the claim _"I want to keep the maximum score for each user-target-item set"_.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear goal but keeping the max score matches the claim. For user A, target D, and type T, we have 2 rows (one with score 0.1 and another with 0.11) and keep user-target-type with the score 0.11.

Comment: What is the column `type F`? Where it comes from?

Comment: It's from the type column in the input table, There are initially type T and F.

Comment: I understand that it is from that column. The rules how it got there are not clear TBH. Especially taking in account the claimed goal _"to keep the maximum score for each user-target-item set "_.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using window functions, especially `row_number`, based on output you want maximum values based not only `user-target-item` but `type` too, so you can try the following:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(user, target, item, score,  type, other_cols) AS (
    values  ('A', 'D', 7, 0.1 , 'T', 'other vals'),
 ('A', 'D', 7, 0.11, 'T', 'other vals'),
 ('A', 'D', 4, 0.2 , 'F', 'other vals'),
 ('B', 'D', 3, 0.4 , 'F', 'other vals'),
 ('A', 'H', 4, 0.3 , 'F', 'other vals'),
 ('B', 'G', 4, 0.1 , 'T', 'other vals'),
 ('A', 'E', 2, 0.2 , 'T', 'other vals')
)

-- query
select user, target, item, score,  type, other_cols
from (select *,
             row_number() over (partition by user, target, item, type order by score desc) as rn
      from dataset)
where rn = 1
order by user, target, item;
```

Which produces:

| user | target | item | score | type | other_cols |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | D | 4 | 0.20 | F | other vals |
| A | D | 7 | 0.11 | T | other vals |
| A | E | 2 | 0.20 | T | other vals |
| A | H | 4 | 0.30 | F | other vals |
| B | D | 3 | 0.40 | F | other vals |
| B | G | 4 | 0.10 | T | other vals |

If you want after that you can aggregate date over `user`:

```sql
-- query
select user,
       filter(array_agg(if(type = 'T', array[cast(item as varchar), cast(score as varchar),  type, other_cols])), arr -> arr is not null) "type T",
       filter(array_agg(if(type = 'F', array[cast(item as varchar), cast(score as varchar),  type, other_cols])), arr -> arr is not null)  "type F"
from (select *,
             row_number() over (partition by user, target, item, type order by score desc) as rn
      from dataset)
where rn = 1
group by user;
```

Output:

| user | type T | type F |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | [[7, 0.11, T, other vals], [2, 0.20, T, other vals]] | [[4, 0.20, F, other vals], [4, 0.30, F, other vals]] |
| B | [[4, 0.10, T, other vals]] | [[3, 0.40, F, other vals]] |

Comment: @nbk now it is closer =)